# Stripe Payment Invalid Request Exception

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I used a Stripe API for payment. When I make payment I get the below error. Please tell me why I'm seeing this error.

> Can only apply an application_fee when the request is made on behalf
>   of another account (using an OAuth key, the Stripe-Account header, or
>   the destination parameter).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) to [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) on behalf of a connected account.

There are two different ways to create charges with Connect:

- [directly on the connected account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#charging-directly), using the [`Stripe-Account`](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header) header, or
- [through the platform](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#charging-through-the-platform), using the [`destination`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-destination) parameter

In both cases, you'd use the `application_fee` parameter to specify your own cut of the transaction.

Which way you use also decides who is responsible for refunds and chargebacks. [This article](https://support.stripe.com/questions/considerations-for-platforms-using-connect) contains information that will help you decide which way is best suited for your needs.

Comment: I am using Stripe Connect and I want the service providers on my platform to be able to receive payments from customers, I have successfully connected the stripe accounts of my sellers with my main account but I dont know how the customers will pay to my platform's sellers? Thanks